# Warning: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined Use

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

Worked just fine yesterday, but today I suddenly got this error when running 'grunt server':

```
Running "bowerInstall:app" (bowerInstall) task
Warning: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I even did a hard reset to the previous commit, but I still get the same error. What could be causing this?

Git repo: https://github.com/oyvindhellenes/Corsane

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Okay this is awkward. A simple 'bower install' did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There are more detail descriptions about it.https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep/issues/36

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks